# Comparing two ManyManyLists in Silverstripe

Tags: php, oop, silverstripe

I want to check if one [ManyManyList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ManyManyList.html) contains any of the objects contained in another ManyManyList in Silverstripe.

BlogCategories are used to categorise content across the entire website:

```
class ServicePage extends Page {

  private static $many_many = array(
      'BlogCategories' => 'BlogCategory',
      'BlogTags' => 'BlogTag'
  );

class CoursePage extends Page {

  private static $many_many = array(
      'BlogCategories' => 'BlogCategory',
      'BlogTags' => 'BlogTag'
  );
```

On a ServicePage I want to display all CoursePages which share either a BlogCategory or a BlogTag with the ServicePage.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Best is to get the IDs of the shared tags and categories using [->getIDList()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-DataList.html#_getIDList), then grab the BlogPosts using [->filterAny()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-DataList.html#_filterAny):

```
$tagIDs = $this->BlogTags()->getIDList();
$categoryIDs = $this->BlogCategories()->getIDList();

$sharedBlogPosts = BlogPost::get()->filterAny([
    'Tags.ID' => $tagIDs
    'Categories.ID' => $categoryIDs
]);
```

Comment: This seems to only work when the BlogPosts contain Tags AND Categories when I would like it to work for BlogPosts that contain Tags OR Categories.

Comment: filterAny() should make an OR statement. You can debug your DataList using ->sql(), e.g. `echo $sharedBlogPosts->sql();` or better in xdebug. PHPStorm e.g. has a nice feature called "evaluate code" (ALT-F8) i use often to get ad-hoc info on a breakpoint.